# PHP echo images in table/grid

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to echo out images in a table/grid format using PHP.

I have a hardcoded html version of what it's supposed to look like so it should help you visualize[image]

I want the 8 videos displayed on the webpage to be selected randomly from a SQL table, is this possible?

Comment: Unclear question, give little more details.

Comment: shown above are the are video thumbnails, right?

Comment: @SubinThomas The image i shown would be the HTML hardcoded version, i want to change it into a PHP file whereby the thumbnails are taken randomly from a pre-fixed SQL database; lets say the top featured videos table here.

Comment: @JunJie, Get latest records by date_uploaded and use your image div inside loop to populate all video thumbs

Comment: It is mentioned that he/she needs records randomly @JunJie. why are you proposing to get latest records.

Answer (score 1):

use this query to return random records from database.

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 8
```

this way you will get random records each time you fire query to databse.

Comment: Hey, these codes are working but the query isn't retrieving the thumbnail correctly. http://imgur.com/TtL8n49 shows my current webpage. Also, do you know how to align it in a table/grid like format? In a 4 x 2 table to be more precise. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you said you have html mock up ready. then just code according to your html structure and echo the image. query is correct. just check the database structure....or paste is over here.

Comment: Yes i do have a HTML mock up thats ready. The image are echoed out correctly but when the title is included, the alignment goes off like this. http://imgur.com/BdfMDR8
I would like to change it to echo like the HTML mock up i provided in the question above, do you know how? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: that depends on how do you integrate your html mockup in the working php code.

Answer (score -2):

This is the most common grid code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=8;$i++)
{
     ?>
     <td><img src="<?php echo $img;?>"></td>
     <?
     if(is_int(i/4)) echo '</tr><tr>';
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```